# New .h file in /usr/include linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I developed small c application in linux. For this application i placed .h file in
linux standard path (/usr/include).  Again i am compiling the same program

**Output:
FATA ERROR : xyz.h(my own header file) not found**

Do i need to update any variable in gcc or way to solve this problem

Thank You

Comment: You should not place your header in the standard headers location. Instead, you need to add to includes path where the header `xyz.h` is. But if the header is in the same location as the source file, then compiler can figure it out by default.

Comment: How are you adding the header file into your code? What is your compile command?

Comment: You could be interested by the `-Wall`, `-v`, `-H`, `-I somedir` options to `gcc`

Answer (score 6):

Place the header file in the same directory as your `.c` file and use `-I.` when compiling

```
gcc -I. main.c -o myprog
```

You shouldn't place your header files in `/usr/include` that is meant for the system headers.

*Note*: you don't actually need the `-I.` because the current directory is searched by default, nevertheless, it doesn't hurt to add it.

Comment: Don't call an executable program `test` (it is a shell builtin). Call it something est like `testprog` or `mytest`; having a program named by a builtin is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Files specified by include directives are meant to be located in one of the search paths of the complier which are specified with the -I option in many cases (at least for gcc, is it the same for other compilers?). The search paths are verified in the order of definition in the command line.

There are 2 kinds of include directives:

- double quoted ones (`#include "xyz.h"`)
- angle bracket ones (`#include <xyz.h>`)

IIRC, the default and first search path for the former is the working directory. For the later, it's compiler dependant, but it's usually `/usr/include/`.

Depending of the include directive you used, you should pick the right location for your file. Or better, put your file in a good location (say the same place as the including file), and add a search path to your gcc command.

Answer (score -1):

You should separate your header `.h` files, from system and repository built headers so you don't break anything.

I would recommend making a folder in your home directory called include and just adding it to your path, that way you never have to worry about it again and no need for the `-I/`flag

Comment: Why not just have them in the project folder... anywhere else makes them a config-control risk

Comment: it won't be an issue if you setup proper namespaces exc.., but this depends if you want to use it within the one project or within multiple projects